# I cannot run DOSBox SVN-Daum on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: dependencies, svn, dosbox

I've got the DOSBox SVN-Duam from its homepage.
Maybe I have solved the dependency problems,

$ ldd ./dosbox
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb776d000)

```
    libSDL_sound-1.0.so.1 => /usr/lib/libSDL_sound-1.0.so.1 (0xb7707000)
    libasound.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2 (0xb7615000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb760f000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb75f4000)
    libSDL-1.2.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0 (0xb7559000)
    libpng12.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0xb752f000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xb7519000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0xb747e000)
    libpcap.so.1 => /usr/local/lib/libpcap.so.1 (0xb7442000)
    libSDL_net-1.2.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSDL_net-1.2.so.0 (0xb743d000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xb7309000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/nvidia-current-updates/libGL.so.1 (0xb722d000)
    libfluidsynth.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfluidsynth.so.1 (0xb7167000)
    libphysfs.so.1 => /usr/lib/libphysfs.so.1 (0xb713c000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb7057000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb702b000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb700d000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb6e62000)
    libvorbisfile.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbisfile.so.3 (0xb6e58000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xb6e4f000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb776e000)
    libpulse-simple.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpulse-simple.so.0 (0xb6e4a000)
    libpulse.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0 (0xb6dfc000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xb6de9000)
    libcaca.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcaca.so.0 (0xb6d1e000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xb6cfd000)
    libnvidia-tls.so.304.64 => /usr/lib/nvidia-current-updates/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.304.64 (0xb6cf9000)
    libnvidia-glcore.so.304.64 => /usr/lib/nvidia-current-updates/libnvidia-glcore.so.304.64 (0xb4ff3000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xb4ef9000)
    libjack.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjack.so.0 (0xb4edb000)
    libsndfile.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1 (0xb4e69000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0xb4e20000)
    libreadline.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 (0xb4de6000)
    libvorbis.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0 (0xb4dba000)
    libogg.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0 (0xb4db2000)
    libpulsecommon-1.1.so => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpulsecommon-1.1.so (0xb4d4d000)
    libjson.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjson.so.0 (0xb4d45000)
    libslang.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libslang.so.2 (0xb4c25000)
    libncursesw.so.5 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5 (0xb4bf4000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0xb4bd5000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xb4bd1000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xb4bca000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xb4b8e000)
    libFLAC.so.8 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8 (0xb4b3f000)
    libvorbisenc.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0xb49c7000)
    libwrap.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0 (0xb49bd000)
    libasyncns.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasyncns.so.0 (0xb49b6000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0xb499c000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0xb4983000)
```

But when I run it,

$ ./dosbox

> DOSBox version SVN-Daum
>
> ### Copyright 2002-2011 DOSBox Team, published under GNU GPL.
>
> GUI: Press Ctrl-F10 to capture/release mouse, Alt-F10 for configuration.
>   CONFIG:Loading primary settings from config file dosbox.conf
>   ./dosbox: symbol lookup error: ./dosbox: undefined symbol: SDL_GetDesktopMode

What's wrong with it? I haven't tried to run it on other Linux distributions. But it's perfect on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can find libSDL-1.2.so.0 in LIBS directory. The file includes a function called SDL_GetDesktopMode.

If you are going to compile SDL yourself, you need Moe's openglhq patch. Get openglhq-dosbox-for-sdl-202121117_msvc_gcc.patch from his website.

Comment: The problem is solved under your help. Thank you very much!